# DIV center align

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have div, which has all content aligned to center:

```
<div align="center">
   <table><tr><td>.....
```

But align is not more valid attribute. So, i have changed to class or style:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
```

But it is not the same as before. Table is now aligned to left and not to center. Obvious text-align is not equivalent to old center attribute. How should i write style to achieve the same functionality as before with center attribute?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: `text-align` ccenters only `inline` items. Table is `table` item so it will not work.

Comment: Volvox, what is then equivalent css style to align="center"?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `margin: 0 auto` on your `table` to center it.

See [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vdsokgcf/)

Answer (score 2):

To align the table to center of the parent element of the table, just use:

```
table {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also to align the table to center in respect of height of the parent element of table, you can give line-height same as height of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above in the comment you need to align the table

Add this to your CSS:

```
table.center {
              margin-left:auto; 
              margin-right:auto;
             }
```

And then add this to your table:

```
<table class="center">
...
</table>
```

Comment: This works, but i have to change inner elements. Is it not possible to say in div that everything inside must be center align?
@Maddy solution doesn't work ok.

Comment: Possibly, but only using older/invalid/unsupported code? This allows for it to be used in multiple instances

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)?

I've used that several times to vertically center content.

Then take a look at bootstrap. They have mix-ins that take care of the horizontal alignment ([here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)).

Edit:

@mattytommo has a good answer for the horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align table to center, use the following

```
<table align="center">
```

This will align your table to centre of div.

Comment: As mentioned in his question align is no longer a valid attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
div{
   width:90%;
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align:center;
}
```

or

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center">
   <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>header</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>data</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div
```